# Theorem $1.7$ in Friedberg's Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I am self-studying *Friedberg's Linear Algebra* and in Section $1.5$, he writes the following:

> ...It follows that *if no proper subset of $S$ (of a vector space $V$) generates the span of $S$, then $S$ must be linearly independent.* Another way to view the preceding statement is given in Theorem $1.7$.
>
> **Theorem $\mathbf{1.7.}$** Let $S$ be a linearly independent subset of a vector space $V$, and $v$ be  vector in $V$ that is not in $S$. Then $S \,\cup \{v\}$ is linearly dependent if and only if $v \in\operatorname{span}(S)$.

I understand the proof of both, the italicized statement and theorem $1.7$, but I am having a hard time understanding how theorem $1.7$ is "another view" of the italic statement. Please explain how both these statements convey the same idea?

Comment: Also I would appreciate if anyone could tell how do i put a vertical solid grey bar on the left side of excerpts taken from book, in stackexchange?

Comment: You put a > at the start of your paragraph.

Comment: oh thanks a lot!! @mrtaurho

Answer (score 0):

Note that the contrapositive of the preceding statement is "if $S$ is linearly dependent then there is some proper subset $T\subsetneq S$ such that $\operatorname{span}(T)=\operatorname{span}(S)$". This is the non-trivial implication of the theorem.

Indeed, if we now take $v\notin S$ and are given that $S\cup\{v\}$ is linearly independent the theorem tells us that $v\in\operatorname{span}(S)$. Hence we can take the proper subset $S\subsetneq S\cup\{v\}$ as *the* proper subset in the preceding statement as $v\in\operatorname{span}(S)$ implies that $\operatorname{span}(S)=\operatorname{span}(S\cup\{v\})$ by definition.